# Worksheet function in VBA code

Tags: vba, function

I have two worksheet functions that work fine when I type them directly in a cell, but when I attempt to run them through a VBA code it doesn't work. The functions are as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">"&DATE(2015,12,31),I:I,"<>"&"",G:G,"=FALSE")

=SUMIFS(I:I,B:B,">"&DATE(2015,12,31),G:G,"=FALSE")
```

The functions are intended to be in cell J14 respectively J15

Can I write a code that does the same job?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "[...] but when I attempt to run them through a VBA code it doesn't work."? How are you trying to run these in VBA and what is not working while you are attempting this? To answer your question: it depends on your VBA skills if you are able to write code which does the same job. Yet, it is certainly possible to write VBA code to mimic these functions.

Comment: You cannot just use functions that you use in a formula directly in the code. Look at the `Application.WorksheetFunction` object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to double up on the double quotes:

```
Range("j14").formula = "=countifs(b:b,"">"" ...
```

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks!